# How to replace string with the number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to replace the comma separated letters in a cell with the numbers. I've used the`=LOOKUP(A1,{"a","b","c","d","e"},{1,2,3,4,5})`  function but it's only working for the single letter.

for example: my desired output:

```
a => 1
```

Comment: Excel doesn't have a Split function, so VBA or Google Sheets can be used for that. Alternative can be to use Text to Columns in Excel Data tab to split the cells into multiple columns

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use the **array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,CODE(UPPER(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))-64)
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

Algorithm:

- Convert comma-separated string to XML: `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"`
- Use `FILTERXML` to convert the XML to an array of strings
- `UPPER` to make case insensitive
- `CODE(…) - 64` to convert to a series of numbers related to the letter)
- `TEXTJOIN` to put the result together

[image]